# Can someone help me fix this error in Swift "Apple Mach-O Linker Error?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, compiler-errors

> > "Linker command failed with exit code 1(use -v to invocation)".

I don't understand what that means and not sure where to go to fix it. I looked at solutions in stackoverflow but none of them are working for me. I cleaned the project also but still not getting rid of the error. Please help.

```
  EDIT


 ld: warning: directory not found for option '-     
 L/Users/welch/Downloads/Flurry'
 ld: warning: directory not found for option '-LiPhone'
 ld: warning: directory not found for option '-LSDK'
 ld: warning: directory not found for option '-LviPhone'
 ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L6.4.0'
 ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L(1)/Flurry-iOS-6.4.0/Flurry'
 ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L(1)/Flurry-iOS-6.4.0/FlurryAds'
 ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F(1)'
 ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/welch/Downloads/IOS-InApp'
 ld: warning: directory not found for option '-FSDK-InApp-2.4.2'
 ld: library not found for -lFlurryAds_6.4.0
 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)


  ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/welch/Downloads/Flurry'


  ld: warning: directory not found for option '-LiPhone'


  ld: warning: directory not found for option '-LSDK'


  ld: warning: directory not found for option '-LviPhone'


  ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L6.4.0'


  ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L(1)/Flurry-iOS-6.4.0/Flurry'


  ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L(1)/Flurry-iOS-6.4.0/FlurryAds'


  ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F(1)'


  ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/welch/Downloads/IOS-InApp'


  ld: warning: directory not found for option '-FSDK-InApp-2.4.2'


  ld: library not found for -lFlurryAds_6.4.0


  clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Usually it means that the code can't compile and when trying to link something that didn't build, the linker fails with error code 1. Can you paste the content of your build output?

Comment: @JohnDifool the clang: error is the one thats not allowing me to run my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on **Build Settings** and under **Library Search Paths**, delete the paths.

Comment: Is it okay to delete all of them?

Comment: I would try without any in there and see the ones it can't find. Then re-add per case. Right now it seems that you have a bunch of paths that go no where. Also the number of issues seems like there are paths with spaces and without any quotes around them.

Comment: okay so I deleted all of them but I still get the clang error. Also the warnings are down to three now.

Comment: Sure, on top of the left column (project navigator), click the right-most icon (show report navigator). Then select the top-most report (latest) and get the detailled output by clicking on the icons on the right to expand the listing. Find the clang ld command and paste it.

Comment: Im sorry it worked. I deleted the flurry sdk and added it again and the error went away. Thanks anyways Ill give you the check mark.

Comment: The error looks like you had no quotes around the library path somehow.